# MVC gives Error Value cannot be null or empty. when i return model to view during updateing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to return model to view to **Preserve** the data that the user entered if there is an exception. So when I return the model to view it tells me "Value cannot be null or empty" but the model still has the data

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

[image]

[image]

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
    {
        using (var db = new NewsDatabaseEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var Result = (from n in db.News.Include("Categories")
                          from c in db.Categories
                          where n.NewsId == Id
                          select new { news = n, neweCategories = n.Categories, cate = c }).ToList();


            News NewsDetails = (from news in Result
                                select new News
                                {
                                    NewsId = news.news.NewsId,
                                    NewsTitle = news.news.NewsTitle,
                                    NewsBody = news.news.NewsBody,
                                    NewsImagePath = news.news.NewsImagePath,
                                    Categories = news.neweCategories
                                }).FirstOrDefault();

            var AllCategories = (from c in Result
                                 select new Category
                                 {
                                     CategoryId = c.cate.CategoryId,
                                     CategoryName = c.cate.CategoryName
                                 }).ToList();



            if (NewsDetails != null)
            {

                var model = new NewsViewModel();
                model.NewsId = NewsDetails.NewsId;
                model.AllCategories = AllCategories;
                model.Categories = NewsDetails.Categories;
                model.NewsTitle = NewsDetails.NewsTitle;
                model.NewsBody = NewsDetails.NewsBody;
                model.NewsImagePath = NewsDetails.NewsImagePath;
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }





    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(NewsViewModel model)
    {


        using (var db = new NewsDatabaseEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            News NewsToUpdate = db.News.Include("Categories").SingleOrDefault(n => n.NewsId == model.NewsId);


            if (NewsToUpdate != null)
            {
                using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {

                    try
                    {

                        db.SaveChanges();

                        transaction.Commit();

                        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Admin", new { Id = model.NewsId });

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        transaction.Rollback();

                        TempData["Error"] = ex.Message + " " + ex.ToString();


                        return View(model);

                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }

        }

        return View();
    }
```

Razor View

```
@model Assignment.Models.NewsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Update News</h2>
<br />


@if (TempData["Error"] != null)
{
    <p class=" alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Error!  </strong>

        @TempData["Error"]

    </p>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewsId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCategoriesIds, new { id = "hid" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Enter News Title", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                    <br /><br />
                    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.NewsImagePath)" alt="Image" id="ImagePreview" width=330 height=250 />
                <br /><br />

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewsImageFile, new { type = "file", data_val = "false" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsImageFile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                <br /> <br />


                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-10">



                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewsBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "ckeditor" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsBody, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <br />
                            This News under these categories: <br /><br />


                            <select id="dropdownOne" name="dropdownOne" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">


                                @foreach (var Category in Model.AllCategories)
                            {



                                if (Model.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).Contains(Category.CategoryId))
                                {
                                    <option selected value="@Category.CategoryId">@Category.CategoryName</option>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <option value="@Category.CategoryId">@Category.CategoryName</option>
                                }
                            }


                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>





        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}
```

Comment: Which line in your view are you getting the error ?

Comment: @Shyju, Thank you for your help. This line

Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control" } })

Comment: this is usually a case of not populating all properties of your model when you return the view after a post.  You need to make sure that whatever properties you populate on your model during the initial httpget action also get populated before you return the model from your httppost.  and also any ViewBag or TempData objects your view needs also get set

Comment: @JamieD77 Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, the infrastructure code which you have written, its not the correct way of passing values across models. In my first book, which is free pdf now, I have made the complete project and shared the code as well like how to data-bind across models or view models. anyways, in this case, try doing one thing, copy the model into session and then from session try assigning the same. i am telling you the workaround. Although, I don't like the way code is written. Going forward follow the deign pattern, I have used here https://github.com/rahulsahay19/Movie-Review

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything you do in your HttpGet action that is required in the View is done again before you return the View(model) in your HttpPost

```
        if (NewsDetails != null)
        {

            var model = new NewsViewModel();
            model.NewsId = NewsDetails.NewsId;
            model.AllCategories = AllCategories;
            model.Categories = NewsDetails.Categories;
            model.NewsTitle = NewsDetails.NewsTitle;
            model.NewsBody = NewsDetails.NewsBody;
            model.NewsImagePath = NewsDetails.NewsImagePath;
            return View(model);
        }
```

you are setting all of the property values when you first load the view but some of these values are null when you return from a failed post.  You can use @HiddenFor() for some of the properties that are not presented as Inputs, but the List objects need to be repopulated from the context

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to official documentation of how to perform CRUD in MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

take a look at Create scenario. User clicks submit and on the server we check for any errors. if no errors in the model - we commit. else we add a error to Model State and return the model back again to view. here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate")]Student student)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

In your case

```
if (NewsDetails != null)
            {

                var model = new NewsViewModel();
                model.NewsId = NewsDetails.NewsId;
                model.AllCategories = AllCategories;
                model.Categories = NewsDetails.Categories;
                model.NewsTitle = NewsDetails.NewsTitle;
                model.NewsBody = NewsDetails.NewsBody;
                model.NewsImagePath = NewsDetails.NewsImagePath;
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

you are redirecting to Index if there was an error. and you are redirecting to Index action. As somebody has mentioned in of the comments above - you need to make sure that the Index action fills up the model before executing the view.

the link i have pasted - contains the Update scenario also. Just go through that documentation and follow along.